# limit of an expression

Tags: limits

I have an expression 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left(x\right)h\left(x\right)}{g\left(x\right)}$$

I know by properties of functions $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=\infty$

But I know that the function $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h(x)=0$

I have searched on textbooks but I did not find a satisfactory information and I have doubt if I must first use Hospital's rule as there is an indeterminate form like $\cfrac{\infty}{\infty}$

Regarding the limit of $g(x)$ function, I have something $\cfrac{\infty \cdot 0}{\infty}$

How should I proceed ? I am not sure if it is possible to conclude as $\cfrac{0}{\infty}$

Thanks in advance for hints.

Comment: Not much can be done unless more is known about $f(x), g(x),$ and $h(x)$.  The limit could be $0$, it could be non-zero but finite, or the limit might not exist (the fraction is unbounded as $x \to 0$), depending on what those functions are.  What else can you say about those functions?

Comment: Take for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{kx^2},h(x)=x,g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k(x)=1/h(x)$, then the if $h(x)$ is continuous and not zero infinitely often, then then $k(x)\to +\infty$ or $k(x)\to -\infty$.

Then write the above as:

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)k(x)}$$

Now the numerator and denominator both go to $\infty$ so you can apply L'Hopital if the functions are differentiable.

Now, $(gk)'(x)=\frac{g'(x)h(x)-h'(x)g(x)}{h(x)^2}$. So you get, when you differentiate the numerator and denominator:

$$\frac{f'(x)h(x)^2}{g'(x)h(x)-g(x)h'(x)}$$

This might or might now be useful, depending on $f,g,h.$

Answer (score 1):

You can't use l'Hopital rule if $f,g,h$ are not derivable. You can't say anything as long as you don't know more about $f,g$ and $h$.